# virtual studio code gui launches fine from my two x-render options [mobaxterm and x-win32/ssh] but fails on Gnome gui remote graphics

Tags: graphics

Latest rpm version of virtual studio code gui launches fine from my two x-render options [mobaxterm and x-win32/ssh] but fails to launch gui from either of my remote graphics Gnome Desktop solutions [x-win32 LIVE and NICE DCV], aside from --disable-gpu, which failed to help, what else would cause this topic when DISPLAY environment variable is set in all cases?